# Insert into the dvdNormal table by joining the dvd, dvdStudio, dvdStatus, and dvdGenre tables

Tags: mysql, database

This is my first time asking a question on here so not really sure of what all information is needed.

I am haveing a little trouble.

```
insert into dvdNormal(dvdId, dvdTitle, year, publicRating, dvdStudioId, dvdStatusId, dvdGenreId)
(
select dvdId, dvdTitle, year, publicRating, studioId, StatusI, genreId
from dvd
join dvdStudio on d.studio = dvdStudio.studionName
join dvdStatus on d.status = dvdStatus.dvdStatusId
join dvdGenre on d.genre = dvdGenre.genre
);
```

Comment: I am sorry if there is not enough information..

Comment: You forgot to mention what problem you're having with this query

Comment: Describing the problem would help - what's wrong with this insert statement? Does it fail Does it produce the wrong results? Also, sharing the tables' structure would be most helpful

Comment: The error message I am receiving is "Unknown column 'dvdTitle' in 'field list'"but that is a column name from dvdNormal

Comment: But you're selecting rows from `dvd` + `dvdStudio` + `dvdStatus` + `dvdGenre`, but **NOT** from `dvdNormal`  - So the inner query it the one that is probably failing

Comment: show your real dvdNormal table schema ..

Comment: I am trying to get information from here http://puu.sh/pyAQf/823ce1118e.png

Comment: and put into this table http://puu.sh/pyAPA/d53caecf28.png

Comment: Try changing `select dvdId, dvdTitle, year, publicRating, studioId, StatusI, genreId` **TO** `select dvdId, DVD_Title, year, publicRating, studioId, StatusI, genreId`